# JavaScript error when returning from controller in MVC

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc

We are seeing an issue where we are returning from a control and the fetch request is not working properly on one of the environments:

Here is the code:

```
    function reloadData() {
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject)
        {
            const urlUpdateData = '@Url.Action("GetUpdatedDataJSON", "Data")';
            fetch(urlUpdateData, {
                method: 'get'
            }).then(function (res) {
                return res.json();
                }).then(function (res) {
                    grid = res;
                }).catch((error) => {
                    console.log("Error: ", error)
                    reject();
            });
        });
    }
```

Here is the error:

**Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0**

Here is how I am returning the data in the controller:

```
        public async Task<JsonResult> GetUpdatedDataJSON()
        {


            return Json(new { data = tasks }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: you're probably getting html (maybe an html error page) back as the response, hence the `<` unexpected token. Use Fiddler or similar to inspect the response and see what you're getting

Comment: @Jonathan you were right! I posted the answer below. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue had to deal with the data in the database and the response coming back in HTML due to the data issue.

We re-imported all the data for the specific schema and everything worked.

Thanks.